# NSMutableArray adds same object each time

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray

I am adding object in `NSMutableArray` it adds but it adds the same object three time instead of different or new.

Calendar Sow Array has data Breedingdate and sow name.

```
for (SOWObject *object in appDelegate.calenderSowArray) {

    temp = object.breedingDate;
    NSLog(@"Date %@",temp);

    [arrayNew removeAllObjects];
    for (indxs = 0; indxs <countOfarray; indxs ++) {

        SOWObject *neObject= (SOWObject *)[appDelegate.calenderSowArray objectAtIndex:indxs];

        NSLog(@"Breeding Date %@",neObject.breedingDate);

        if ([temp isEqualToString:neObject.breedingDate]) {

            [arrayNew removeAllObjects];
            [arrayNew addObject:neObject];
         }
     }

     [testArray addObject:arrayNew];

 }
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Rashad I am adding the same date objects in arrayNew after that adding that arrayNew object to testArray

Comment: [arrayNew removeAllObjects]; [arrayNew addObject:neObject]; why this lines? You are removing everything then adding? Why?

Comment: So you want the same data in a new array named testArray ??

Comment: so what is countofarray? where did it come from? are you having array of pointers to arrays. you need to elaborate your calendarsowArray for people to understand and support. Also what is data at start & expected end result.

Comment: Its a logical part. Please debug the code. U should get what you are missing.

Comment: @svrushal thanks i am debugging it

Answer (score 0):

Check if the array contains the object before adding. By doing this a particular object will be added only once.

```
 if(![arrayNew containsObject:neObject]) // if arrayNew does not contain neObject, add it to the array
{
       add it to the array 
}
```

or if your testArray is adding same objects, then,

```
 if(![testArray containsObject:arrayNew])  // if testArray does not contain arrayNew, add it to the array
    {
           add it to the array 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (SOWObject *object in appDelegate.calenderSowArray) 
    {
         [testArray addObject:object];
    }
```

This alone should be enough if you want to add all the SOWObject's in appdelegate.calendarSowArray into the TestArray.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to create an array of arrays, however the inner array always contains exactly one element.  If this is what you want then:

```
for (SOWObject *object in appDelegate.calenderSowArray) {

    temp = object.breedingDate;
    NSLog(@"Date %@",temp);

    for (indxs = 0; indxs <countOfarray; indxs ++) {

        SOWObject *neObject= (SOWObject *)[appDelegate.calenderSowArray objectAtIndex:indxs];

        NSLog(@"Breeding Date %@",neObject.breedingDate);

        if ([temp isEqualToString:neObject.breedingDate]) {
            [testArray addObject:@[ neObject ]];    // This creates a new inner-array each time        
         }
     }
}
```

And if not (you just want an array) then:

```
[testArray addObject:neObject];
```